# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'model_type' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `media`

Tags: laravel-queue, laravel-medialibrary

I am using these two packages:

```
"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^10.0.0",
```

I'm importing an Excel sheet with queuing and when a cell contains URL-s, then I am using medialibrary's addMediaFromUrl() like this:

```
$media = $product
            ->addMediaFromUrl($string)
            ->preservingOriginal()
            ->toMediaCollection(Product::MEDIA_COLLECTION);
$media->save();
```

The importer file is prepared to work in queues:

```
class ADOBProductsImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, WithHeadingRow, WithChunkReading, WithEvents, ShouldQueue
{

  /**
   * @see https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html
   * 
   */
  public function chunkSize(): int
  {
    return 10;
  }

  ...

}
```

Model looks like this:

```
  public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
  {
    $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
      ->setManipulations(['h' => 100, 'fm' => 'png', 'fit' => 'max'])
      ->performOnCollections(self::MEDIA_COLLECTION)
      ->queued();

    $this->addMediaConversion('medium')
      ->setManipulations(['h' => 600, 'fit' => 'max'])
      ->performOnCollections(self::MEDIA_COLLECTION)
      ->queued();

    $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
      ->setManipulations(['h' => 100, 'fm' => 'png', 'fit' => 'max'])
      ->performOnCollections(self::MEDIA_MAIN)
      ->queued();

    $this->addMediaConversion('medium')
      ->setManipulations(['h' => 600, 'fit' => 'max'])
      ->performOnCollections(self::MEDIA_MAIN)
      ->queued();
  }
```

...when I'm importing the Excel sheet, I receive this message I mentioned in the subject. Any idea?

I tried to not use queue, but then even if I have no errors not saving the images though...